# Why do you need conditional variables when you have mutexes?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore, condition-variable

I've taken a look at a Wikipedia pseudo code showing the consumer-producer problem solution using semaphores and mutexes:

```
mutex buffer_mutex; 
semaphore fillCount = 0;
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE;

procedure producer() {
    while (true) {
        item = produceItem();
        down(emptyCount);
            down(buffer_mutex);
                putItemIntoBuffer(item);
            up(buffer_mutex);
        up(fillCount);
    }
}

procedure consumer() {
    while (true) {
        down(fillCount);
            down(buffer_mutex);
                item = removeItemFromBuffer();
            up(buffer_mutex);
        up(emptyCount);
        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

This solution seems to me like it would work pretty well, But how exactly will condition variables help us here? From what I understood a CV will block the calling thread until a certain condition is met, But the 'down' operation or a 'lock' operation also blocks the calling thread if the the value is 0. So is it all about integers vs conditions or is there more to it?
Thanks.

Comment: It is programmers responsibility to notify("lock, unlock") CV and in OS responsibility to lock, unlock mutex;

Comment: This depends upon how you want the producer/consumer program to work. The lock operation prevents overlapping reading and writing, but it does not ensure that the consumer only reads new values, or that the producer does not override unread values. Without the use of condition variables the producer/consumer creates a consumer that only samples some of the values produced. Using condition variables allows the consumer to read every value produced exactly once.